# PHPMailer Ignoring \r\n

Tags: php, formatting, phpmailer

I am currently having an issue with emails received that were sent from PHPMailer using plain/text emails. I am currently returning the email message from a database by fetching the row and saving into a variable $message. The message while in the database is formatted as such:

```
This is some email information. \r\n This is some more email information.
```

The email received is showing the message with the \r\n rather than returning a new line.

My PHPMailer Code looks similar to the following:

```
$subject = $row['subject'];
$message = $row['message'];

// PHP Mailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = "noreply@mywebsite.org";
$mail->FromName = "MyWebsite.org";
$mail->AddAddress('recipient@email.com');
$mail->ContentType = 'text/plain';
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;
if(!$email->Send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

**My question**: How can I get \r\n to format properly using PHPMailer? Is this a PHPMailer setting or am I doing something wrong within my code?

Comment: well you probably did write `\r\n`as a string in the value contained in your field, while you should use characters 10 (equivalent to `\n`) & 13 (equivalent to `\r´) instead. So, you should correct the way you insert thi in your DB and for existing records either you update them that way, either you adapt your output code to replace the escaped strings with the chracater they refer to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you've saved `\r\n` into your database as text - PHP will not parse that. You need actually save a new line into your 'message' in the database

Comment: $message = str_replace(array('\r', '\n'), array("\n", "\n"), $row['message']); should help

Comment: @AdamFischer That removed the \r\n from displaying in the email. However there are no line breaks present where the \r\n had occurred.

Comment: Sorry, $message = str_replace(array('\r', '\n'), array(chr(10), chr(13)), $row['message']); this should work for you.

Comment: Did you tryed to print the $message to your browser? No linebreaks there?

Comment: @AdamFischer When I print the message to the browser there are no line breaks there either.

Comment: Just tested the code, and I have them. Are you sure your source data is exactly what you have posted here?

Comment: @Ryan, when you say there are no line breaks in the browser is this when viewing the source or not? If you're viewing it as HTML the line breaks produced won't show.

Comment: So it appears viewing the source the line breaks are present. Odd. So I'm thinking that my email client is viewing the email as HTML rather than plain text at this point.

Comment: That's good - that shows @AdamFischer's code is working as expected. Using that `$message` in your email should work correctly if it's being interpreted as plaintext. Can you checkout the headers that your email client is receiving? (There's normally a "View Headers" / "View Original" / "View Source" option somewhere)

Comment: Try to remove AltBody as it is used only in html emails

Comment: Removing the AltBody seems to have worked. I really appreciate the effort and help on this.

Comment: I just replaced \n\r with <br>

Answer (score 14):

This might just be a simple case of using single quotes instead of double quotes when originally preparing the message.

Using single quotes will result in \r\n being stored in the database as part of the string, and PHPMailer will then output \r\n in the email instead of an actual line break.

Using double quotes will fix the problem.

For example, `$message = 'Line 1\r\nLine 2';` (single quotes)
will be output as

```
Line 1\r\nLine 2
```

while `$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2";` (double quotes)
will be output as

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

This works for me, even if using AltBody to send both HTML and Plain Text versions of an email.

Comment: Using single quote and double quote does make a difference on how PHP interprets \r\n. Thank you, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 11):

Ryan mentioned this in the comments for the other answer, but I struggled with this and felt this deserved it's own answer.

Removing the AltBody has worked. It looks like this.

```
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
```

This seems to be the case whether $mail->isHTML() is set to true or false. I'm not sure why this seems to be the case. Perhaps the client me and Ryan were sending to accept only plain text emails, and AltBody not only sends plain text, but actually remove line breaks. If you need to send an HTML message that won't show tags if the client can't accept tags, then I suspect you'll either have to live with it or dig into the PHPMailer code

Comment: yeah! somehow when AltBody is not set, and when the body is plain text it respects line breaks, not if you set it! weird...

Answer (score 7):

Simply make nl2br() on the string ... but out of phpmailer... and then write a string into the body" ";  and no need to use preg_replace or something like that.

I will explain step-by-step

```
$string = nl2br($_POST["message"]);
```

after that in the body of the php mailer write just like this

$mail->Body    = "$string";

And that is.. so simple...OK

Comment: StackOverflow supports using Markdown (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to apply syntax highlighting to code examples.

Comment: Seriously? This solved my problem! I just need to convert the message body with nl2br. Thank you!!

Comment: Yeah but then that's no longer a plain-text email. That's HTML.

Answer (score 3):

```
$body = stripcslashes(isset($body) 
? 
preg_replace('#(\\\r|\\\r\\\n|\\\n)#', '<br/>', $body) 
: 
false);
$body = str_replace("<br/><br/>","<br/>",$body);
```

This works for me!

Comment: Yeah but then that's no longer a plain-text email. That's HTML.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but the solutions provided did not work for me. However the following did work so I thought it might be worth sharing.

`$body = nl2br($body);`

Comment: Yeah but then that's no longer a plain-text email. That's HTML.