# \n is not giving me a new line in my HTML

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm writing a PHPEmailer file and I have `isHTML` set to true and I also have this to format my output:

```
$mail->Body = 
    "Name: " . $_POST['quote_name'] . 
    "\r\n\r\nCompany: " . $_POST['quote_company'] . 
    "\r\n\r\nPhone: " . $_POST['quote_phone'] . 
    "\r\n\r\nAddress: " . $_POST['quote_address'] . 
    "\r\n\r\nCity: " . $_POST['quote_city'] . 
    "\r\n\r\nState: " . $_POST['quote_state'] . 
    "\r\n\r\nZip: " . $_POST['quote_zip'] . 
    "\r\n\r\nInspirational Link: " . $_POST['quote_link1'] . 
    "\r\n\r\nInspirational Link: " . $_POST['quote_link2'] . 
    "\r\n\r\nInspirational Link: " . $_POST['quote_link3'] . 
    "\r\n\r\nInspirational Link: " . $_POST['quote_link4'] . 
    "\r\n\r\nProject Details: " . stripslashes($_POST['quote_details']);
```

But the email is coming out like this:

> Name: John Doe Company: Coca Cola Phone: 5552345678 Address: 123 Main St City: New York State: NY Zip: 17011 Inspirational Link: Inspirational Link: Inspirational Link: Inspirational Link: Project Details: a sample text

What I want is each of those fields in its own line

Comment: if `isHTML = true;`, then you have to write `<br>` instead of `\n`, isn't it?

Comment: hmmmm...interesting. I though the HTML would take effect at output time but I would still have to code it in PHP syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer Ignoring \r\n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839027/phpmailer-ignoring-r-n)

Comment: @LOTUSMS I thought I'd explain why here, but instead wrote it in the answer

Comment: 3+k rep you can do better :-)

Comment: @Dagon, you are right. I'm a UI/UX developer. I don't deal with server side languages too much. And I specifically hate PHPMailer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `isHTML` into `true` for PHPMailer, it would **not** *take effect at output time*, as you state in the comments to your question. It only sets the flag to send a header section indicating the e-mail is an HTML one: `Content-type:text/html;`, nothing else.

So what you actually need to do is to replace all your `\r\n` with `<br>` tag, otherwise you don't get your line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

`\r\n` in HTML doesnt mean anything; you need a `<br>` tag instead

### edit:

`\r\n` could still be useful for readability of the source HTML, but it will not produce line breaks in the HTML output

Answer (score 2):

Your email is set to html.  Us a br tag instead.

```
"<br>Company: " . $_POST['quote_company'] .
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<br/>` instead of `\r\n\r\n`, since HTML is enabled.

If you want to use `\r\n\r\n`, you'll need `nl2br()`:

```
<?php
    Body =  nl2br("\r\n\r\nCompany: ");
?>
```

Comment: Using `<br>` is fine. but I do like this option. You never know when you may be forced to use the other option. Nice

Answer (score 1):

`</br> is used to insert line breaks in HTML.`

You can try it out [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp).